# How to check Kubuntu 15.10 for errors

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, 15.10, error-handling

I have recently installed kubuntu 15.10, but while installing the installer crashed and i was left at 97%. So i rebooted the Computer and it was working perfectly well, but from time to time my computer wont wake up from sleep, or sometimes just freeze.
So how do i check the whole OS for errors and repair these?
Is there some way to reinstall kubuntu without overwriting Data that has nothing to do with the OS, or just adding anything that is missing?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do a check is, **before** installing the [Ubuntu 15.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/), you should check the [SHA1](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/sha1sum.1.html) hash :

You can do it by typing :

```
sha1sum {file}
```

If you want to send the file together with its sha1sum output redirect the output to a file:

```
sha1sum {file} > {file}.sha1
```

Comment: yes, i know that (ubuntu even provides the sums), but isnt there any way to, say, download a program that knows what files have to be installed on the os and installs them if they aren't there?